# Display issue of three-backticks formatted code

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, code-formatting

I came across [an answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53180817/apollo-client-making-optimistic-updates-while-creation-is-still-in-progress/53277720#53277720) whose code is formatted with triple backticks (AKA CommonMark / GitHub style / ```), that layouts weirdly:

[image: Weird layout]

When I edit the question, the preview looks good:

[image: Wonderful preview]

<sup>This was tested under Firefox 67 & Chrome 75, connected or not, with or without Chrome plugins activated.</sup>

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SO: [Code block rendered incorrectly at question but correct in edit window](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385524/4642212).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code fences weren't supported until January 2019, so any post that used them before then had them rendered as simply inline code. You do need to edit and save in order for the post to be rendered using the new Markdown processor.

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks! He used it in Nov '18 though, as he knew for sure it would be deployed in 6 to 8 weeks